# How do I get the latest date from a collection of objects using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have a list of objects and each object has a  **ExpirationDate** property which is of type **DateTime**. I want to retrieve the latest date in the list. Is there an elegant way of doing that through LINQ?

Something like:

```
DateTime latestDate =  myCollection.Where(r=>r.ExpirationDate.HasValue).MaxDate(r=>r.ExpirationDate.Value);
```

Comment: What is the behaviour you want if the collection is empty or if there are no items with an ExpirationDate set?

Comment: @BobVale if ExpirationDate is of Type DateTime every r will have an ExpirationDate. As DateTime is a struct, ExpirationDate  can never be null.

Comment: @Offler But if you look, the OP uses `ExpirationDate.HasValue` and `ExpirationDate.Value` indicating that ExpirationDate is of type `DateTime?` (ie `Nullable<DateTime>`)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
DateTime? latestDate = myCollection.Max(r => r.ExpirationDate);
```

Intellisense should have given you the Max() method. =)

---

Now, if you must assign it to a DateTime, I would consider doing thus:

```
DateTime latestDate = myCollection.Where(r => r.ExpirationDate.HasValue)
                                  .Max(r => r.ExpirationDate)
                                  .Value;
```

This will not cover the case of an empty collection or a collection with only null ExpirationDates.

---

Depending on your earlier logic, checking

```
myCollection.Any(r => r.ExpirationDate.HasValue)
```

might be a good idea before trying to assign a value.

Comment: Heh, it did look right to me too, but where's the MaxDate()? :)

Comment: The where condition is unecessary, also Type will be DateTime? not DateTime so this code will error.

Comment: The where condition was removed earlier - missed the DateTime?. =)

Comment: @J. Steen - i want to return a DateTime (not a DateTime?)

Comment: @ooo, Yeah, I figured. Edited. =) This won't cover the case if myCollection is empty or full of nulldates.

Comment: @J. Steen- i will check for empty collection up front

Comment: @ooo - its not just empty collection, its also if none of your values have an expiration date.

Answer (score 8):

You are almost there. Use Max:

```
DateTime? biggest = myCollection.Max(r=>r.ExpirationDate);
```

If all expiration dates are null or the collection is empty you will get Null as a result, otherwise the greatest date.

As you have commented on [J. Sheens' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775050/how-do-i-get-latest-date-from-a-collection-of-objects-using-linq/6775076#6775076) that you want an DateTime as a result you will need to do something about any empty collection or no items with a value, you could do this with

```
DateTime biggest=myCollection.Max(r=>r.ExpirationDate) ?? DateTime.MinValue
```

This will give you `DateTime.MinValue` instead of nulls in my previous example (it also has the advantage over using the `any` clause that it iterates the collection once). I picked `MinValue` as an example. You could use your own abitary date.

Using the DateTime? is better, because it allows you to use null for what it's meant to mean - undefined as `MinValue` could be a valid item in your list.

Answer (score 3):

Just make sure there is a NullReference check before assigning `.ExpriationDate`:

```
DateTime maxDate = myCollection.OrderByDescending(o => o.ExpirationDate).Take(1).FirstOrDefault().ExpirationDate;
```

[Bob Vale had](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775050/how-do-i-get-the-latest-date-from-a-collection-of-objects-using-linq/6775070#6775070) the right idea with

```
DateTime maxDate = objL.Max(o => o.ExpirationDate);
```

Comment: Is the Take(1) necessary as you have FirstOrDefault()?

Comment: No.  You can't ever get a null reference exception on a `DateTime`.  DateTime is a value type, which means it resides on the stack.  `NullReferenceException` is for reference types (on the heap).  See code: `DateTime dt; Console.WriteLine(dt.ToShortDateString());`.  `Nullable<DateTime>` works the same way.

Comment: @mattmc3 - But the type would not be a DateTime, the type would be the surrounding class, The poster was indicating that FirstOrDefault could return null, so you would get a null reference exception when you accessed the ExpirationDate property on the end

Comment: Matt the null exception does throw if you try to access a property on the .First() if the collection is empty..its' not on DateTime that it is throw but on the object containing the datetime.

Comment: Bob, no you are correct...I was rushing out door this morning and shoudl have slowed down...Take(1) is not required if you use First or FirstOrDefault()

Comment: You're right - I missed that the result wasn't a DateTime but an object with a DateTime property.

Answer (score -1):

Sort the list by the date descending and take the first (projecting if necessary).

```
var latestExpirationDate = myCollection
    .Where(item => item.ExpirationDate.HasValue)
    .OrderByDescending(item => item.ExpirationDate)
    .Select(item => item.ExpirationDate) // DateTime?
    .FirstOrDefault();
if (latestExpirationDate != null)
{
    // do something with the value stored in latestExpirationDate
}
```

---

As I wrote this, I was under the impression that the `Max()` method only operated on numeric types (i.e., int, short, decimal, etc.).  It appears to work with `DateTime` objects too.  So this could work as well:

```
var expiredItems = myCollection
    .Where(item => item.ExpirationDate.HasValue);
if (expiredItems.Any())
{
    var latestExpirationDate = expiredItems.Max(item => item.ExpirationDate.Value);
    // do something with latestExpirationDate
}
```

Comment: Not necessary since it was projected to the date first.

Comment: First() will throws an exception with an empty collection

Comment: Ok so what?  Big deal.  That was not a constraint in the question and therefore not a concern for us.

Comment: Max() operates on IComparables. =)

Comment: @J.Steen: Which I had realized after trying to verify the solutions that used `Max()`.  :)

Comment: Because you haven't documented your return value when there are no dates set in the collection or the original collection is empty.

Comment: @Bob: Again, not our concern.  Those sorts of checks should be done prior to querying the collection anyway if the goal is to utilize LINQ effectively.  Since he specifically asks for the `DateTime`, this is how it would have to be done.  I could certainly offer suggestions to make this better but that would mean changing what he wants and how he wants it, I won't go there, I don't have the time.

Comment: @Bob: Ok updated, I had the time now (it was late late for me and needed some sleep).  ;)  Everything satisfactory?

Comment: Looks good to me, it's not me thats voted you down btw, but I've voted you up.

Comment: It works yes but really bad for perf, what if you have 1 million objects in your list ? You're gonna sort just to take the max ? 
Sorting at worst : O(n^2) 
Max at worst : O(n)